# Solution to $\frac{\mathrm dh}{\mathrm dt} =\frac{−\alpha} {r}h$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the following problem:

> In a highly viscous fluid, a falling spherical object of radius r
>   decelerates right before reaching the bottom of the container. A
>   simple model for this behavior is provided by the equation
>   $$\frac{\mathrm dh}{\mathrm dt} =\frac{−\alpha} {r}h$$ where $h$ is the height of the object measured
>   from the bottom, and α is a constant that depends on the viscosity of
>   the fluid.
>
> Find the time it would take the object to drop from $h=6r$ to $h=2r$ in
>   terms of $\alpha$ and $r$.

So in order to solve the problem, I did the following:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm dh}{\mathrm dt} &=\frac{−\alpha} {r}h \\
\int \frac{\mathrm dh}{h} &= \int \frac{-\alpha}{r} \mathrm dt \\
h &= e^{\frac{-\alpha}{r}t}e^{C} \\
2r &= 6re^{\frac{-\alpha}{r}t} \\
\frac{1}{3} &= e^{\frac{-\alpha}{r}t}\\
\end{align}$$

Here is where I have an issue. In order to get rid of the $e$, I should use $\ln$ on both sides but one of the solutions shows the following:

$$-\log 3 = -\frac{\alpha}{r}t$$

Instead of $\ln \frac{1}{3} = \frac{-\alpha}{r}t$ How come? Can someone please explain the reasoning behind that? I have a feeling that it is something simple and for some reason I can't see it.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that $\log(1/3)$ is negative, and then there is a minus sign on the other side. So really two negatives. That's two many. In physical situations, it is nice to have as many of our constants as possible positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply for $x>0$ we have $$\log\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=-\log(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

It's one of the log laws:

$\log {1\over3} =\log 3^{-1} = -\log 3$